# Overridding a value with Providers array not working with lazy loaded modules / routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-providers

I have an app module that is doing:

```
export const MY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<any>('MY_TOKEN');
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ApiModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MY_TOKEN, useValue: 'hello' },
  ],
  ...
```

that app routing module has a route:

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: () => import('./open.module').then(m => m.OpenModule),
},
```

That open module is doing:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    OpenRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MY_TOKEN, useValue: 'lol' },
  ],
```

and then the open routing module has a path that that lazy loads a module / component

```
{
  path: 'some/where',
  loadChildren: () => import('./something.module').then(m => m.SomethingModule),
},

...
```

Ok, so next, I have an HTTP interceptor that is provided in the `ApiModule` ...

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MyInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
})
export class ApiModule {}
```

and in that intercepter, I am doing:

```
constructor(
  @Inject(MY_TOKEN) public val: any
) {
  console.log(val);
}
```

When the component in the open module makes api calls, the value is `hello` rather than  `lol`...

I thought at first this might be because the interceptor is getting instantiated before the module that gives the provider for the token, so then I tried using the injector directly in the interceptor:

```
intercept(
  request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
  next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
  console.log(this.injector.get(MY_TOKEN));
  ...
```

But that still logs `hello` instead of `lol` ...  Why is the provider I specified in the Open module not getting used?

Comment: Include how you're providing the interceptor e.g. is this in AppModule.

Comment: @AndrewAllen I updated my question to add the ApiModule where the interceptor was being provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could figure out how to do this was to initially have an object set and mutate that object in the various modules...

```
export interface Context {
  open?: boolean;
}
export const context: Context = {};
export const CONTEXT = new InjectionToken<Context>('CONTEXT', {
  providedIn: 'root',
  factory: () => context,
});

// app module:
{ provide: CONTEXT_TOKEN, useValue: context },

// open module
export class OpenModule {
  constructor(@Inject(CONTEXT) context: context) {
    context.open = true;
  }
}

// other modules
export class ModuleXYZ {
  constructor(@Inject(CONTEXT) context: context) {
    context.open = false;
  }
}
```

Now the interceptor has the correct state.......  I really just wanted to be able to not have this http interceptor be applied to things in the Open module, but that apparently was not possible because when I initially tried providing the http interceptors in the further down modules then they were never being applied...  So I have had to resort to this dumb "context" code so that the interceptor can do:

```
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    if (this.context.open) {
      return next.handle(request);
    }
    ...
```

If anyone has any suggestions on how I can do this in a less dumb way, I'd greatly appreciate it..

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you're observing, where the MY_TOKEN provider in the OpenModule is not getting used, is expected because Angular's Dependency Injection system follows a hierarchy when resolving dependencies, and it uses the nearest provider it can find in the hierarchy. In your scenario, the ApiModule provides the MyInterceptor, and when the MyInterceptor is constructed, it tries to resolve the MY_TOKEN dependency. The nearest provider of MY_TOKEN it finds is in the AppModule, not the OpenModule, so it uses the MY_TOKEN value from the AppModule.

Here's a simple explanation of what's happening:

When the MyInterceptor is constructed, it looks for the MY_TOKEN provider in the dependency injection hierarchy.
It finds the MY_TOKEN provider in the AppModule, so it uses the value 'hello' specified in the AppModule.
To achieve your desired behavior, where the MY_TOKEN from the OpenModule is used, you can follow these steps:

Remove the MY_TOKEN provider from the AppModule.

Keep the MY_TOKEN provider in the OpenModule.

Comment: Then I get `No provider for InjectionToken MY_TOKEN!` errors when api calls are tried outside of the module..  I then tried using `@Optional()` in the constructor, but the value then is always null (I assumed because interceptors are instantiated once before the token is created).. So then I tried in the `intercept` function doing: ` this.injector.get(MY_TOKEN, null)` and it's always null despite api calls being initiated from a component in the Open module that has the provider.  So... I don't understand what is going on.

Comment: It seems that the problem is the interceptor will always has the wrong injector... And I tried adding the ApiModule to the OpenModule instead of AppModule, and then the interceptors are never used at all.........  seems like a disaster.